# How to overcome overlapping series lines in highcharts spline

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a trend chart implemented using highcharts, the data is loaded via json dynamically. The chart renders properly with the data but however the series lines, data labels and symbols overlap each other at given data points. How do I overcome this?

Find the link to Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ashanwijenayake/ft0ke201/

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5ZHv.png)

```
function renderTrendChart(){                                
    $("#trendChartContainer").highcharts({    
        title: {
            text: 'Indicator Vs Action Trend Chart',
            x: -20 
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: trendChartCategoies
        },
        yAxis: {
            minRange: 1,
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0, 
            title: {
                text: 'Cases Identified'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {               
                pointPadding: 10,
                groupPadding: 10,
                cursor: 'pointer',
            }
        },
        series: [{"name": "Pneumothorax", "data": [ { "y": 1, "marker": { "symbol": "text:" }, "dataLabels": { "x": -10, "y": -2, "enabled": true, "format": "2", "style": { "fontWeight": "bold", "fontSize": "12px" } } },{ "y": 2, "marker": { "symbol": "text:" }, "dataLabels": { "x": -10, "y": -2, "enabled": true, "format": "2", "style": { "fontWeight": "bold", "fontSize": "12px" } } } ], "id": "Pneumothorax" },{"name": "Respiratory", "data": [ 0,{ "y": 1, "marker": { "symbol": "text:" }, "dataLabels": { "x": -10, "y": -2, "enabled": true, "format": "1", "style": { "fontWeight": "bold", "fontSize": "12px" } } } ], "id": "Respiratory" },{"name": "Exsanguination", "data": [ 0,{ "y": 2, "marker": { "symbol": "text:" }, "dataLabels": { "x": -10, "y": -2, "enabled": true, "format": "3", "style": { "fontWeight": "bold", "fontSize": "12px" } } } ], "id": "Exsanguination" }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: It would be great if you can add your code, or fiddle?

Comment: Check it out, trendChartSeries is a JSON object which is pre-populated and stored as global variable. The markers and labels are included in the JSON object.

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, you can experiment with data labels options: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.dataLabels

Comment: Check out the fiddle for more code clarity.

Comment: If your data points for a give `{x, y}` are the same between multiple series then they will overlap - that is unavoidable. You can specify to use `tooltip: {shared: true}` to show all points' values at a given `x`.